# Connecting a remote controlled ceiling fan to 3 way switch

Tags: ceiling-fan

I recently bought a remote controlled ceiling fan that I am trying to install. 
The bedroom where I'm installing it has two light switches and two ceiling fans currently.
I have removed one of the ceiling fans. 
There are two cables entering the box. One cable has a black, red and white wire, the other has a black and white. 
(It's an old house. Neither have a ground wire.)

The 2 black wires were paired, the red and white were paired and a single white wire.

What's confusing me is why the red and white wires are paired. I know they are linked to the light switch but I'm unsure of why they were paired.

What am I looking for is a way to have constant power for the fan but have the light controllable from the wall switch as well as the remote.

Comment: Do you want the remote to be able to dim the lights on the fan?  Or does your report not support dimming?

Comment: The ceiling fan I purchased does not support dimming.

Comment: What size is the existing ceiling box?  Also, can you post a photo of the fan receiver module?

Comment: The existing ceiling box is a 4".https://postimg.org/image/dentq3pi5/

Comment: Here it is connected to the orginal ceiling fan before I removed it https://postimg.org/image/v1q20uwh7/

Comment: Do you want to rewire the switch loop with a /3 cable, or would you rather preserve it?

Comment: I'd rather preserve it only because of limited access to the wiring.

Comment: If you're still here -- would you be willing to introduce an extra box alongside the existing fan box?